# Is there any Jenkins configurations/plugin which only runs test cases for changed files in Java projects?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, build

The project I'm working on consists of 600 unit test cases and around 1300 java files. Currently, we are using Jenkins for building the final docker image for this service. It takes around 25mins for the build to complete which is too much. We have many other services also and that makes it impossible to run on local systems. My questions here is, Is there any plugin or Jenkins configuration which would only run the test cases of changed files only and reduce the overall build time?

Comment: Please note that such requests arent in the scope of this community: we do not recommend libraries, tools, ...

Comment: Changes in class may break other classes and their tests. 
So if you test the changed classes only, you will not get a guarantee that everything works.

Comment: Considered building the image first without tests and then only promote it if the tests pass

Comment: @Danesh Changer, you can have dynamic relationships between classes that cannot be found with static analysers. Something that can only happen "at runtime" (e.g. java-reflection-based dependency injection). So, I'm not sure that what you're looking for is generally possible.

Comment: @Gmugra (edit: corrected the name) Agreed. Basically, the plugin/tool should make a graph of affected classes and run tests for those only.